# How to check that Visual C++ 2013 redistributable is already installed using WiX bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper, redistributable, visual-c++-2013

I am trying to create a bootstrapper for WiX installer. I need to install VC++ 2013 redistributable packages (for both x86 and x64 platforms). And I want to skip the installation of these packages if they are already installed. To do that I add next elements to product.xml for each package:

```
<InstallChecks>
  <MsiProductCheck
    Property="IsMsiInstalled"
    Product="{?????????????????????????}"/> 
</InstallChecks>

<Commands>
  <Command PackageFile="vcredist_2013_x86.exe">
    <InstallConditions>
      <BypassIf Property="IsMsiInstalled" Compare="ValueGreaterThan" Value="0"/>
```

So the question is: what product code should be?

After Google didn't help me I tried to extract vcredist_2013_x86.exe and look at msi file properties but that was another problem. After extracting it using 7Zip I got only bunch of files with strange names like: "0", "u0", "u1", "u2" etc. File "0" turned out to be Burn manifest. It contained product codes: for x86: `{13A4EE12-23EA-3371-91EE-EFB36DDFFF3E}` and for x64: `{A749D8E6-B613-3BE3-8F5F-045C84EBA29B}`. So I tried to use them but no luck. `MsiProductCheck` returned -1 despite the package was installed.

Then I looked what changes happen in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall registry key (I'm working on Win8.1). Keys added during installation and removed after deinstallation were different: `{ce085a78-074e-4823-8dc1-8a721b94b76d}` for x86 and `{7f51bdb9-ee21-49ee-94d6-90afc321780e}` for x64. But they didn't work with `MsiProductCheck` too. It's result was still -1 (unknown product) even if they were installed.

So I am in despair now. The only idea I have is to use `RegistryCheck` instead of `MsiProductCheck` and check for keys in Uninstall. But I would like to know what is the problem here. What product code should be used for VC++ 2013 redistributables? Why the only keys that are added during package installation don't work for `MsiProductCheck`?

Comment: You should be using the [merge module](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_vcredist.html) to install the redistributable, not the .exe.  The merge module will handle everything correctly if its already installed.

Comment: The problem with merge modules is that I need both x86 and x64 packages but Wix doesn't allow me to add modules for different platforms.

Comment: Well, now you've got a different problem.  MSI does not allow you to build installer packages for both x86 & x64 into the same installer.  You should have two separate installers and use Burn or some other bootstraper to install the correct one. [See Here](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/single-msi-for-32-bit-and-64-bit-tp6358749p6358844.html)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by you needing to do the check. The redist packages are already doing that check and if you just run them (silently with the appropriate command line if required) they just go away quietly if they don't need to do anything.